# How to change Uploading text in upload component in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to customize "uploading" text in upload component while uploading in antd. But I can't find any thing in antd doc to help me.
here is doc:
https://ant.design/components/upload/

[image]

Comment: Try to get into the component who owns the Uploading progress bar and see its properties or maybe you can try getting into the id of the element though css or JS. Can you show me some code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the position of `content`, you need to customise `top` and `left`.
I have changed the CSS attributes of other elements(red color of the plus icon, Upload text of another card) as well. You can change them as per your needs. Here is a quick [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58773378-fleu6).

[image: pic]

```
/* plus +  icon*/
.ant-upload-select-picture-card i {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
}
/* Upload text*/
.ant-upload-select-picture-card .ant-upload-text {
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: red;
}

/* Uploading... text*/
.ant-upload-list-item-info
  > span
  > div[class="ant-upload-list-item-uploading-text"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* you need to customise top and left css attribute */
.ant-upload-list-item-info
  > span
  > div[class="ant-upload-list-item-uploading-text"]:after {
  content: "Wait ?";
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```